# Panel que muda de tamanho C#

Tags: c#, .net, eventos-do-mouse, panel

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer o seguinte para minha aplicação *Windows Forms C#*. Tenho um *Panel* que, ao ativar o seu evento `MouseHover`, o panel expande seu tamanho e ali dentro do panel com tamanho maior eu quero adicionar funcionalidades.

```
private void panel1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Size = new Size(200, 250);
}

private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Size = new Size(25, 30);
}
```

Ao tentar adicionar uma *checkedListBox* nesse *panel* reparei que ao passar o mouse por cima da *checkedListBox* que está dentro deste *panel*, o evento `MouseLeave` do *panel* é acionado. Vocês poderiam me ajudar com esse problema? Não estou sabendo o que fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o evento `MouseLeave` desta forma:

```
private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.GetChildAtPoint(panel1.PointToClient(MousePosition)) == null)
    {
         panel1.Size = new Size(25, 30);
    }
}
```